# How do I add data: { turbolinks: false } to an a href inside of a controller flash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code works perfectly:

```
def create 
  flash[:info] = %Q[<a href='#{url_for(edit_user_path(user))}'>Please click here to edit your profile</a>]
end
```

However, I need to add data: { turbolinks: false } or the equivalent into the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe put a div around your flash message in your view layout and disable turbolinks on the parent div.

```
def create 
  flash[:info] = %Q[<a href='#{url_for(edit_user_path(user))}'>Please click here to edit your profile</a>]
end
```

and in your layout-view something like:

```
<div class="flash-info" data-turbolinks="false">
  <%= flash[:info] %>
</div>
```